# Python - find highest dictionary key with value greater than zero

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
{0: 12, 1: 1, 2: 13, 3: 7, 4: 0}
```

I want to find the highest dictionary key with a value greater than 0.

In this case, the answer is 3.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: What should be returned if all the keys are negative or non-numeric?

Comment: `max([i for i,j in k.items() if j > 0])`

Comment: For my use of this, the keys won't be negative or non-numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max` and `dict.items()` to do this:

```
d = {0: 12, 1: 1, 2: 13, 3: 7, 4: 0}

highest = max(i for i,j in d.items() if j > 0)
```

Comment: can't call max on empty lists. Errors if None to return.

Comment: @kpie I'll leave that to OP to figure out for themselves. I've answered the question exactly how they wanted. For anything else they should open a new question. Otherwise it's just me writing their whole code for them.

Answer (score 3):

Use a genexpr to filter out the "bad" values, and `max` to keep the highest that remains:

```
# On Py2, use .iteritems() instead of .items()
max(k for k, v in mydict.items() if v > 0)
```

Or if you need to have a default if no keys qualify without an exception being raised:

```
# Py3 max has default, which makes this super-easy:
max((k for k, v in mydict.items() if v > 0), default=SOMEVALUEGOESHERE)

# Py2 doesn't have default; workaround is to catch exception and use a default (EAFP):
try:
    mymax = max(k for k, v in mydict.iteritems() if v > 0)
except ValueError:
    mymax = SOMEVALUEGOESHERE

# Or if you can't do that for some reason, make a listcomp instead of genexpr
# and check for at least one surviving key before calling max (LBYL)
goodkeys = [k for k, v in mydict.iteritems() if v > 0]
mymax = max(goodkeys) if goodkeys else SOMEVALUEGOESHERE
```

Comment: Doesn't account for empty list exceptions.

Comment: @kpie: Hmm? What about it? The comment says no keys will be negative or non-numeric, but that's irrelevant to the answer here. It's checking the values, and (optionally) handles the possibility of the `dict` having no keys with a positive value. __Edit__: Comment changed, but yeah, I added handling for that immediately after posting, that's why `max` can take a `default` argument.

Comment: default isn't an option for max in python 2.

Comment: @kpie there are plenty of things wrong with your own answer that I think you should fix first before nitpicking other people's answers

Comment: @kpie: True. Forgot that was new in Py3, and op didn't specify version. Added solutions to handle it.